# fork+exec pattern could be substituted by system(run-command-in-background)?

Tags: c, unix

If the fork and exec patter is used just to run a program without freeze the current program, what's the advantage, for example, over using this single line:

```
system("program &"); // run in background, don't freeze
```

Comment: Generally, one should avoid using `system()`, because it's non-portable, and, unfortunately, it's actively used as a hackish solution by programmers who don't know a proper solution for a problem.

Comment: What if someone uses a console where appending `&` is not the way to go to run a process in the background?

Comment: `system()` is also clearly massively less secure than fork/exec, depending on where you're getting the argument string from and the security context of the application...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `system` function creates a new shell instance for running the program, which is why you can run it in the background.  The main difference from `fork`/`exec` is that using `system` like this actually creates two processes, the shell and the program, and that you can't communicate directly with the new program via anonymous pipes.

Comment: Actually, to even more strongly discourage `system()`, note that `fork/exec` creates *exactly* one new process. `system` creates *at least* two new processes, but depending on what is in your shell startup files, it can create many, many more....

Answer (score 1):

fork+exec is much more lightweight than system(). The later will create a process for the shell, the shell will parse the command line given and invoke the required executables. This means more memory, more execution time, etc. Obviously, if the program will run in background, these extra resources will be consumed only temporarily, but depending on how frequently you use it, the difference will be quite noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) clearly says that `system` executes the command by "calling /bin/sh -c *command*", which means system creates *at least* two processes: `/bin/sh` and then the program (the shell startup files may spawn much more than one process)

This can cause a few problems:

- portability (what if a system doesn't have access to `/bin/sh`, or does not use `&` to run a process in the background?)
- error handling (you can't know if the process exited with an error)
- talking with the process (you can't send anything to the process, or get anything out of it)
- performance, etc

The proper way to do this is `fork`+`exec`, which creates *exactly* one process.  It gives you better control over the performance and resource consumption, and it's much easier to modify to do simple, important things (like error handling).